# How to programmatically append directive to angular-ui accordion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I've tried to programmatically append a custom directive to an angular-ui accordion via $compile mechanism. I'm using a so-called main directive whose template contains the accordion markup. In the link function, I try to do something like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var setEl = function (obj) {

            var el = $templateRequest('assets/templates/testing.html').then(function (html) {

                var template = angular.element(html);

                var parent = element[0].querySelector('#test-0');

                angular.element(parent).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {

                    parent.append($compile(template.contents())(scope));
                });

            });
        };

        var getDir = function (title) {

            var obj = {

                title: title,
                el: null,
                isHeaderOpen: false
            };

            setEl(obj);

            return obj;
        };

        scope.dirs = [

            getDir('first')
        ];
    },
```

In my HTML I have:

```
 <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="dir in dirs">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-click="testing()">
            {{dir.title}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                        ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': dir.isHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !dir.isHeaderOpen}"></i>
        </div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <span id="test-{{$index}}">{{dir.el}}</span>
</div>
```

However, what gets appended is: `[[Object Text]]`

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: i think that you should compile the html like that 
`parent.append($compile(html)(scope));`

Comment: I just get the following appended: [[object Comment], [object Text], [object HTMLDivElement], [object Text], [object Comment]]

Comment: ok forget about what I said. I assume that you have more than one root element in these template and that's maybe the reason it doesn work.